# Frattini subgroup not Fully Invariant

Tags: group-theory

Let be $G$ a group. Why is the Frattini subgroup $\Phi(G) := \cap \{M | M $maximal subgroup of $G \}$ not fully invariant subgroup? Therefore there exist a endomorphism $\phi: G \to G$ such that $ \phi(\Phi(G)) \not\subset \Phi(G)$? Has anybody a conterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathtt {SmallGroup}(48,30)$ is a counterexample. This is a subdirect product of $C_4$ and $S_4$, which you could take to be the subgroup $\langle a,b \rangle$  of $S_8$, where $a=(1,2,3,4)(5,6)$ and $b=(6,7,8)$.

Its Frattini subgroup is the group $\langle (1,3)(2,4) \rangle$ of order $2$.
The homomorphism $\phi:G \to G$ that maps $a \mapsto ab$ and $b \mapsto 1$ maps $\Phi(G)$ to $\langle (1,3)(2,4)(5,8)(6,7) \rangle$.

Comment: Do you see a more sophisticated way to conclude that the Frattini subgroup of thisgroup is $\langle (1,3)(2,4) \rangle$
than to count down all possible maximal subgroups?

Comment: Do you mean subdirect product of $C_4$ and $A_4$?

Comment: No I meant $C_4$ and $S_4$.